# How i can make json correctly in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have two tables, in the first first I have keys, in second I have values. When i try to make JSON, I get array of JSON, but I want get only one ONE. How i can make it?

What I have:

| Table 1 |
| --- |
| key |
| KEY |

| Table 2 |
| --- |
| value |
| VALUE |

What I got:

```
[
    {"key" : "value"}, 
    {"KEY" : "VALUE"}
]
```

What I want to got:

```
{
    "key" : "value",
    "KEY" : "VALUE"
}
```

Query:

`SELECT jsonb_build_object(Table1.key, Table2.value)
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 USING(guid)`

Comment: The first question is - can you share the method you are using to get the JSON from your database? Without this we're flying blind to your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to aggregate the JSONB objects.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(Table1.key, Table2.value)
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 USING(guid)
```